# C# Possible To Have User Input Set Console Colors?

Tags: c#, console

I created a simple console game and quite happy how it turned out so just making some final tweaks and i thought since I set the console colors for background and text, could I let the user chose the colors? I know it may be a can of worms, but now that I tried and it wont let me set the following, I at least want to know if this is possible. Here is what I tried.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter desired background color for this screen: ");
var screen = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter desired text color for this screen: ");
var text = Console.ReadLine();
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.screen;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.text;
```

The error VS gives is ConsoleColor does not contain a definition for screen and text.

Thanks to Hayden for getting me on the right track, came up with this:

```
     Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter desired background color for this screen: ");
     string back = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), back, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you're receiving the error is due to `ConsoleColor.screen` and `ConsoleColor.text` doesn't exist (which is not the same as `screen` and `text`).

To achieve users wanting to change the console colour, you can try the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter desired background color for this screen: ");
var screen = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter desired text color for this screen: ");
var text = Console.ReadLine();
// Attempt to parse the colors that the user entered into their respective enum values.
// The new values of background and foreground will be set to the user input
if(Enum.TryParse(screen, out ConsoleColor background))
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = background;
}
if (Enum.TryParse(text, out ConsoleColor foreground))
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = foreground;
}
```

Comment: thanks! so it accepts it, but after entering the text color it gets stuck, i am just entering white and then blue, just to test if it works, not getting an error, just can keep hitting enter forever

Comment: Have edited code. Note you will need to enter the colors exactly as described in `ConsoleColor` (if you're using visual studio, right click on `ConsoleColor` and click Go To Definition).

Comment: after you got me on the right track, this is for a class so still learning C#, but I came up with the line I added to the bottom of my OP, what do you think?

Comment: After edit by @SimpliFixed this post no longer answers the question (it does not even look like question anymore)